# In Python, what is the reference count of cyclic reference and why?

Tags: python, cyclic-reference

Here is a example of a cyclic reference of Python.

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> b = [2]
>>> a.append(b)
>>> b.append(a)
```

after this,

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(a) = 3
>>> sys.getrefcount(b) = 3
```

Why do `a` and `b` have a reference count of 3??

Sorry guys i just took a mistake.

the real question is the different one.

```
>>> GNU = ['is not Unix']
>>> GNU.insert(0, GNU)
>>> sys.getrefcount(GNU) = 4
```

Why is the reference count of 'GNU' is 4 ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I can't reproduce your last example.

Comment: i'm using 2.7.5 version now. well it works on my program.

Comment: Still can't reproduce your updated question. `from sys import getrefcount as r;g=[0];r(g);g.insert(0,g);r(g)` → 2, 3; Anyway, try checking the refcount *before* and *after* the insert. Maybe what you don't understand isn't what you think you don't understand.

Comment: I think i should have thought deeply next time when questioning. Thanks really a lot~ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 references to each:

1. In the other's list in the first element.
2. As an argument to `sys.getrefcount()`.
3. The current scope, i.e. bound to `a` and `b`.

Comment: …can you explain why deleting `b` would increase `a`'s refcount? (Although I have not been able to reproduce that here with Python 2 or 3.)

Comment: @kojiro: Nope. But I don't think we're seeing everything either.

Comment: oh then when delete b, why the reference count of a becomes 4 ?

Comment: @user2522245: No one can reproduce your results; there's something you're not telling us.